# How to disable the default routing and specify manual one in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js

First of all, please don't waste your time to overpersuade mе to use Nuxt default directory-based routing: I need the manual routing and that's it.

No updates in ["Vue router 4 support" issue](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module/issues/110) of [@nuxtjs/router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/router) since May 30, 2022 - looks like no way except dealing with manual routing myself if I need it.

I have checked the [source code](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module/blob/main/src/module.ts) of **@nuxtjs/router** - the is no much code, but I have not understood where the manual routing has been set to Nuxt.

It is required to do 2 things:

1. Disable the default routing
2. Set the new routing

For the Nuxt 2.X, the disabling part was

```
if (!options.parsePages) {
  this.nuxt.hook('build:before', () => {
    this.nuxt.options.build.createRoutes = () => {
      return []
    }
  })
}
```

In the Nuxt 3.X case, there is no `createRoutes` property anymore.

Then, how I can to specify the new routing?
There is the dedicated property?

We can start with inline plugin definition:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig, NuxtConfig } from "nuxt/config";


export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  modules: [
    async (inlineOptions: unknown, nuxt: NuxtConfig) => {

    }
  ]
});
```

By the way, if to try to use the current **@nuxtjs/router** for Nuxt 3, it will be [this error](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module/issues/123).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the module anymore in Nuxt3. Now you can create a [`router.options.ts`](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#custom-routes) in the `/app` folder and edit or fully override the routes

Answer (score 2):

in Nuxt3, you can use [RouterConfig](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#router-options) for activating manual routing, follow these steps:

1. create ./app/router.options.ts file
2. create ./pages/login.vue file for testing
3. insert this code on ./app/router.options.ts:

```js
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema'

export default <RouterConfig>{
  routes: (_routes) => [
    {
      name: 'login',
      path: '/login',
      component: () => import('~/pages/login.vue'),
    }
  ],
}
```

now you can access http://localhost:3000/login using manual routing.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others mentioned, you have to add a `app/router.options.ts` file.

However, one missing piece is you also need to add `<NuxtPage />` in your `app.vue`, giving the matched route a place to render.

Some links for reference:

- https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/custom-routing#using-router-config
- https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-page